# Background execution of commands

Tags: python, function, sockets

I have a connection from a server to a client.
I'm interacting from my PC (in this case the server) to another PC (in this case the client). Let's say that I'm downloading a file from the client, the program is waiting that the download ends. Is there a way that while my PC is still downloading, to process other commands or spawn a new shell that let me run some command that the client will execute without open a new connection?

code:

```
def Exec(cmde):
# check if command exists
if cmde:
    execproc = subprocess.Popen(cmde, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    cmdoutput = execproc.stdout.read() + execproc.stderr.read()
    return cmdoutput

# otherwise, return
else:
    return "Enter a command.\n"
```

I use the above code to execute command, but this command let me interact with the shell. To execute other customized command (like download a file, whatever...) I define a function like above. Let *down* and *up* be the function that let me download a file, so upload a file:

```
def Down(socket, file):
...

def Up(socket, file):
...
```

I'd like to make a function that let me executed a command or whatever in background. While I run *Down* :

```
[*]Downloading file...
[*]Wait a while...
[*]Download finished
```

So what I'd like to is something like:

```
[command2exec]: BackgroundDownload filename.file
[*]: Downloading in background filename.file
[command2exec]: ls (for example)
[output]:
...
[command2exec]:
...
[!]: filename.file's download finished.
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a new tab or window... Downloads should naturally run in the background... Not sure if this is the right place for you to ask that question.

Comment: If I open a new shell I will interact with my PC, not with the client (that is what I want)

Comment: Can you specify that in your description, along with examples and any programming attempts you have done?

Comment: Question edited. I don't know what examples post because I didn't tried, because I don't know where to start.